# Как вытащить из tree необходимые данные?

Tags: java, дерево

Столкнулся с следующей проблемой: Есть структура данных Tree

```
{"table" : [ {
"dayWeek" : "Понедельник",
"lesson" : [ {
  "numSubject" : "",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : "",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
} ]}, {
"dayWeek" : "Вторник",
"lesson" : [ {
  "numSubject" : "",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : "",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
} ]}, {
"dayWeek" : "Среда",
"lesson" : [ {
  "numSubject" : "",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : "",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
} ]} ],"name" : "Группа","specialty" : "Специальность"}
```

Необходимо вытащить данные, чтобы при выводе получилось следующее:

```
Группа:Группа
Понедельник
1. -
2. -
3. Предмет
   Препод (каб)
4. Предмет
   Препод (каб)
5. -
6. -

Вторник
 Ну и так далее...
```

Так же не знаю как объяснить, но мешает ещё то, что в Tree всё съехало на 1 позицию. Т.е.

```
"dayWeek" : "Понедельник",
"lesson" : [ {
  "numSubject" : "",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : "",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
} ]}
```

Но должно быть: (И так со всеми днями)

```
"dayWeek" : "Понедельник",
"lesson" : [ {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : "Предмет",
  "numTeacher" : "Препод (каб)",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
}, {
  "numSubject" : " ",
  "numTeacher" : "",
  "denSubject" : " ",
  "denTeacher" : ""
} ]}
```

Если что, то данные получаю с парсинга сайта и то, что съехало на 1 позицию - мешает. Жалобно прошу помочь :(

Comment: так а в чем проблема разобрать json и дальше работать с данными?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеки либо для data binding, либо для работы с деревом JSON.

Вот, например, фрагмент решения вашей проблемы через Jackson, далее можете сделать по аналогии и с помощью [документации](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html):

```json
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public final class Main {
    private Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var json = """
                {"table" : [ {
                "dayWeek" : "Понедельник",
                "lesson" : [ {
                  "numSubject" : "",
                  "numTeacher" : "",
                  "denSubject" : "",
                  "denTeacher" : ""
                }]}],"name" : "Группа","specialty" : "Специальность"}""";

        var om = new ObjectMapper();
        var node = om.readTree(json);
        System.out.println("Группа:" + node.get("name").textValue());
    }
}
```

Проблема с тем, что у вас съехал список ответов, легко решаема, если при переборе дочерних узлов пропустить первый объект.